# How to set Request Headers in Nextjs 9

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, apollo-client

I have been reading the [Headers](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/network/headers/) section on zeit.co to try and work out how to set my `authorization: "Bearer ${token}"` headers for auth. But I cannot see anywhere in the documentation on how to set custom Request Headers.

My attempt with `apollo-link-context` does not seem to bare any fruit sadly. Which I thought, its possible `nextjs` is changing them?

```
  const authLink = setContext(_ => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    }
```

Comment: Next is not related to ajax requests at all, you need to attach it to your fetcher, (such as apollo-client, axios, fetch)

Comment: Thanks Felix. Am I not doing that with the above code? `at least I believed the context was populating the headers for the request.

Comment: You are doing that @JamieHutber. I'm running into the same problem with client-side headers. The only header that's being set is "Authorization". The rest just seem to disappear.

You are missing a piece though. The `setContext` call is a bit off. You are not retrieving the original headers, first and foremost. Not sure if that's triggering a silent error, since `...headers` spreads over undefined — you don't seem to be getting the `headers` variable from anywhere. 

`const authLink = setContext((event, { headers }) => { ...`

That's the signature. No space for the whole code.

Comment: @JamieHutber here's a gist with the way I use `authLink` - https://gist.github.com/oprearocks/0c8c93054aa76cefd103400c80168c06

It works/worked when I was using Firebase Auth.. but now I'm authenticating everything using my own AUTH system and since I enabled SSR for GraphQL queries I've been struggling with it. Still, I believe you can use it in your app. Currently running in production at weremote.eu